# Unable to send SMS from Journey Builder using mobile number from contact data

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobileconnect, sendsmsactivity

I am trying to send an SMS from Journey Builder using contact data for mobile number as opposed to an entry source attribute. The SMS does send but only to contacts who are already in the MobileConnect list. These contacts entered the list in a previous journey where I used entry source data and subscribed them to a key word.

The settings for my new journey are:

1. Entry source is a data extension
2. Subscribe Contacts to a key word
3. Use mobile number attribute from Contacts

The entry source DE for this journey does not have a mobile number but I have linked an attribute set which includes this in data designer. The number includes international code and there is a locale field.

Are there any suggestions on how I can send SMS using contact data to contacts who are not already in the mobile connect list?

Comment: Hi, Please check that you have an 'Active' opt in message in your mobile connect that is linked with your 'ADD' keyword. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_mobile_opt-in.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks Swati - I have just added this message and tried again but the SMS is still not sent to new contacts.

Comment: If you've no mobile number in your entry data and the contact doesn't have a mobile number established in Mobile Contacts, how's Journey Builder going to tell what the contact's mobile phone number is?

Comment: I have a data extension linked to the contact in data designer which does have the phone number in it. I thought this would be accessible via the contact data but it seems that's not the case. I am going to set up an automation to import new contacts into mobile connect channel so I can then hopefully send via contact data.

Comment: This was the missing step - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_import_mobile_contacts.htm&type=5